# Preventing check boxes from being checked/unchecked

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a workbook that has many checkboxes (form control) on one tab.  I check the box (Yes/No/NA) based on values in other tabs,.  The tab with the checkboxes, is a form that was created, that needs to be printed, but the users cannot click any of the boxes because these decisions are driven by formulas.

I have locked the workbook & unchecked all the boxes in the popup.

So the question is, how do I prevent all the check boxes from being clicked/checked??

AHIA,
LarryR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Form Control:

1. Right-click and select `Format Control...`
2. Select the `Protection` tab.
3. Make sure that `Locked` is checked
4. Select the `Control` tab.
5. Choose a cell in the `Cell Link` field.
6. Press `OK`.
7. Right-click on the cell that you referenced in step 5.
8. Select `Format Cells...`
9. Select the `Protection` tab.
10. Make sure that `Locked` is checked.
11. Select `Hidden` if you don't want users to see it.
12. Press `OK`.
13. Right-Click on the Worksheet Tab
14. Select `Protect Sheet`
15. Make sure that `Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells` is checked.

That should do it!

Comment: There is no Properties on right click, but there is Format Control, where there is a Properties tab, but no enable option....

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Excel 2007 and I have both Format Control **and** Properties.

Comment: Are you sure that it's an Active-X checkbox and not a Form Control?  (Form Control has no properties but Active-X does).

Comment: That did the trick, I attempted everything you suggested prior to my post, except 7-10.

Comment: Yeah, that part isn't obvious.  You'd think that they would mention that (after all, they do say that you need to protect the sheet, lol).

Answer (score 0):

Protect the cells with the check-boxes, and when you click on protect Sheet uncheck the Select locked cells from the list of what the users are allowed to do after the document is locked; that way they'll be able to see but not click on those cells.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same issue and ive solved the issue by right click on the sheets and there is a grouping selection, ungroup it and the checkbox works again.